# Flux threw Dispatcher is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux, jspm

I try to use jspm with reactjs. I worked fine. But when I integrated it with flux package from npm. Then it always threw **Dispatcher is not a constructor** error. 
My code as below

AppDispatcher.js

```js
import Flux from 'flux';
export default new Flux.Dispatcher();
```

StoreBase.js

```js
'use strict';

import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatchers/AppDispatcher';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

export default class BaseStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    subscribe(actionSubscribe) {
        this._dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(actionSubscribe());
    }

    get dispatchToken() {
        return this._dispatchToken;
    }

    emitChange() {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    }

    addChangeListener(cb) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, cb)
    }

    removeChangeListener(cb) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, cb);
    }
}
```

I used reactjs@0.13.3, react-router@0.13.3 and flux@2.0.3. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: have you found out why is this happening or how to solve this?

Comment: @stkvtflw check Ajay's answer below

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Babel you can use below

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';
const dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
export default dispatcher;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should export the `Dispatcher` as follows

```
import Flux from 'flux';
export default new Flux.Dispatcher;
```